# Dealing with mistakes in recording the dataset in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have a dataset that has a rather complicated problem. It includes 600,000 observations. The main issue is related to the data collection process. As an example I provided the following dataset that has  similar structure to the real datast I have in hand:

```
df <- data.frame(row_number = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-02","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-03","2020-01-03"),
                time = c("01:00:00","09:00:00","17:00:00", "09:00:00","01:00:00","17:00:00", "01:00:00","NA","09:00:00"),
                order = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                value = c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30,NA,50)
```

I know in each day the data was recorded 3 times (order variable). That is in each day, the first time in which the data was recorded was 1:00:00, the second time in which the data was recorded was 09:00:00 and the last time in which the data was recorded was 17:00:00.

However, the person who collected data has made mistakes. For instance, in row_num 4, the time is supposed to be 01:00:00, however, the data collector recorded 09:00:00.
Also, in row number 8 I expect the time should be 9:00:00, however, since there was no information was recorded in value, the person did not fill that row and rather recorded the time to be 09:00:00 at order number 3 while it is expected that the time in order number 3 is 17:00:00.

Given the fact that we know the order of the data collection, I was wondering if you have any solution to deal with such an issue in the dataset.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a group of 3 rows and give time in the order we want :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number/3)) %>%
  mutate(time = c('01:00:00', '09:00:00', '17:00:00')) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-grp)

#   row_number date       time     order value
#       <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1          1 2020-01-01 01:00:00     1    10
#2          2 2020-01-01 09:00:00     2    20
#3          3 2020-01-01 17:00:00     3    30
#4          4 2020-01-02 01:00:00     1    40
#5          5 2020-01-02 09:00:00     2    10
#6          6 2020-01-02 17:00:00     3    20
#7          7 2020-01-03 01:00:00     1    30
#8          8 2020-01-03 09:00:00     2    NA
#9          9 2020-01-03 17:00:00     3    50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time <- c("01:00:00","09:00:00","17:00:00")
rep(time, 200000)
```

[image]

The `rep()` function allows you to *repeat* a vector as many times as you want for your dataset. This allows you to create the 3 time slots for observations, and then repeat them for you 600,000 observations, so you can eliminate humane error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I should have written my question differently. Sorry about that. The datasets I included in my question is an example of what I have in my hand. In fact, my dataset includes about 600,000 observations some of which are recorded as it has been explined in the question.

Comment: updated my answer, hopefully I am giving you more of what you were looking for